# Geometry Nodes: instance another geometry

Tags: geometry-nodes

I created a stem using Geomtry Nodes and now I would like to instance it in a circle to have kind of a bush, but I can't find the way to instance an object created with geometry nodes. I don't want to apply the geometry nodes modifier because on its geometry nodes set up I created some random variables (for the size and rotation of the leaves) that I would like to keep.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution i know is...add another object with GN like this:

GN1:

[image]

GN2:

[image]

result:

[image]

So it is still procedural and you don't have to apply - but you have two objects with two different geometry nodes modifiers.

Comment: Trying to duplicate this.  Seeing the answer without the steps in between isn't helping.

How do you get from GN1 to GN2?

Comment: First create a cube and a sphere. Add GN to cube (that’s GN1). Then add a torus. Add GN to torus with GN2.

Comment: @unkerjay: you should write: isn‘t helpful for you or beginners - but isn’t helpful isn’t true, else I wouldn’t have got the check and an upvote…but yeah, if you never used geometry nodes it might be unclear.

Comment: I stand corrected.  "isn‘t helpful for me or beginners"